# Gradle Build sample fails with "You must assign a Groovy library to the 'groovy' configuration."

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a build.gradle file (from the custom plugin example in the manual) that reads:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

dependencies {
compile gradleApi()
compile localGroovy()
}
```

But when I run I get:

```
$ gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> You must assign a Groovy library to the 'groovy' configuration.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: I was on the version provided by fedora v1.0.x, I noticed that was out of date some I'm upgrading now.  Will that fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, upgrade to a newer version.

The above problem (and a few more) where happening on v1.0.8, upgrading to v1.6 and its all works properly

Comment: BTW, I strongly recommand you use the Gradle wrapper instead of relying on a local install of Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have both:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
```

and use the **groovy** keyword in the dependencies section (rather than using the **compile** keyword):

```
dependencies {
   groovy 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.8
}
```

All credit to [this blog](http://zxmax.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/helloworld-with-groovy-and-gradle-1-1/).

Comment: Looks like the original author was using Gradle version 1.x together with manual version 1.y where x < y. In recent Gradle version, `compile` is correct (and preferred).

Comment: That is correct.  For Gradle post 1.4 (current version at the time of writing is Gradle 1.8) you'll get the message:    The groovy configuration has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Typically, usages of 'groovy' can simply be replaced with 'compile'. In some cases, it may be necessary to additionally configure the 'groovyClasspath' property of GroovyCompile and Groovydoc tasks.
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Can you elaborate on "manual version" and how this would differ from the Gradle version?

Comment: "manual version 1.y" = Manual (i.e. user guide) for Gradle version 1.y.